# Помогите понять работу 'or' в данном контексте (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть цель - проверить email адреса на наличие символов (провалидировать)
Пишу простой цикл с таким условием:

```
for _str in f.readlines():
    if ',' or '('  in _str.strip():
        foo()
    else:
        bar()
```

При применении данного условия функцией foo начинают обрабатываться не только строки, где действительно встречаются данные символы, а все строки подряд.
Если я убираю or - всё обрабатывается правильно.
С чем это связано.

Также просьба подсказать способ для обработки сразу на множество условий, типа:

```
if foo([',','/'], or)  in _str.strip():
```

Можно ли применить что-то в таком духе? (Код абсолютно выдуман, но суть примерно должен передавать)

Знаю, что есть регулярки, но несколько регулярок отработали на данном массиве плохо и мне быстрее валидировать через условия

Comment: ``','`` это True.

Comment: В целом, да, это решает вопрос, почему-то забыл этот момент.
Но наверняка есть лаконичный способ записи ``if ',' in _str.strip() or '(' in _str.strip()  :``

Comment: ``if any(s in _str for s in symbols)``, где symbols - список с нужными символами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка в (почти) одну строчку без циклов

```
symbols = [",","("] # список с проверяемыми символами
if any(s in _str for s in symbols): # проверка
    # do your stuff
```

Comment: но фактически any - просто синтаксический сахар, хотя довольно удобно конечно.

Comment: @xmikex Ну да. Но если так рассуждать, то и max(), и math.sin() и много чего еще, включая некоторые модули целиком, итертулс, например, тоже синтаксический сахар :)

Comment: Вообще не совсем так. Математические функции вряд ли вообще реализованы в питоне через вычисления с помощью интерпретатора питона.

Comment: @xmikex нет, конечно. Но ведь сам питон всего лишь сахар к с/с++ :)

Comment: @xmikex А чем вы предлагаете заменить `any`? Сахар - это когда можно и без этого оператора обойтись. Но чтобы без `any` обойтись придётся в принципе по-другому код писать.

Comment: "True" in (s in _str for s in symbols) и (s in _str for s in symbols).__contains__("True") чем принципиально от any будут отличаться?

Answer (score 1):

До кучи ещё такой вариант предложу:

```
if any(map(_str.strip().__contains__, (',', '('))):
```

Просто проверяем, входит ли хоть одна строка (символ в данном случае) из кортежа в проверяемую строку.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что хотя синтаксис питона во многом похож на простой английский язык, вы не можете просто написать так, как если бы вы писали это на человеческом английском.

`or` (так же как и `and`) - это не просто слова, а логические операторы, которые работают по определённым правилам. Чтобы получить то, что вы хотите, вам надо писать так:

```
if ',' in _str.strip() or '('  in _str.strip():
```